# How do I convert time difference into a decimal weeks value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

So in my database I have 2 dates I want to get the difference between.  They are in the format 2013-07-31 00:00:00.  I want the different in weeks, not time.  So say date 1 - date 2 = 3 days and 12 hours.  I want this to be represented as a week, as in 0.5 weeks.  How can I do this in my sql query?

NOTE:  I want the value returned to be a decimal, e.g. 1.5 not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide you a whole number:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, date1, date2) AS weeks;
```

To include a fraction for days, use:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date1, date2) / 7 AS weeks_days;
```

or a fraction for seconds, use:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date1, date2) / 604800 AS weeks_secs;
```

as 604800 is 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;

Here's an example:

```
SET @date1 = NOW() - INTERVAL 777 HOUR, @date2 = NOW();
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,   @date1, @date2) AS weeks, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,    @date1, @date2) / 7 AS weeks_days,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @date1, @date2) / 604800 AS weeks_secs;
```

returns:

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| weeks | weeks_days | weeks_secs |
+-------+------------+------------+
|     4 |     4.5714 |     4.6250 |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: You should be more careful, especially before revising an answer with 164 upvotes. Which manual were you referring to?